# Change the default Icons OS X 10.4.11 Tiger

Tags: software-recommendation, icon, macos

So, I really would like to change my icon set on my iBook G4, but I really have no clue how to do it!

I have the icons (I believe all are in either .png or .ico), but I have little/no experience on Macs! I know I can go program by program and change icons by clicking on <kbd>Get Info</kbd> after right-clicking, but changing the entire icon set via that would take forever and I would be sure to miss some.

Basically, does anyone know of OS X Tiger compatible software that will swap icons out for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at CandyBar software from the Icon Factory.

It supports 10.2!!! and later and does exactly what you ask. Free trial to be sure it does what you wish so you don't need to spend any money if it's not to your taste.

http://iconfactory.com/software/candybar

Comment: This worked great for most of the stuff. Is there any way I can change the icon of a certain app (in my case TenFourFox)? I tried doing it through the normal way of copy and pasting the .icns from preview, but that puts either a white or black border around it. As for doing it through CandyBar, dragging in any png, ico, icns just puts that place-holder icon in instead of the actual icon.